# STM32 Embedded GUI Library porting for F4 Discovery

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to use the [STM32 Embedded GUI Library](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00259585.pdf) with STM32F4 Discovery Board.
Has anyone already done a porting of this library on the discovery?
Otherwise, how can I try to port it and what is the "weight" in terms of work of such a porting? (I'm new in programming embedded devices)

Comment: It looks like it was written for STM32F10xxx, STM32L1xx, and STM32F2xx series of micros.  As such, you'll need to update the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) for your specific micro (STM32F4xxx).  See section 4.4 of the .pdf you linked to for what you'd need to update.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a look at µGFX: https://ugfx.io

It comes with a ton of optional features and built-in drivers. Your hardware setup is already supported.

Answer (score 1):

I used Littlev Grapics Library (free, open source) on STM32 discovery. Maybe you will like it too. 
http://www.gl.littlev.hu/blog/8/embedded-gui-on-stm32-discovery-board-with-littlev-graphics-library

It comes with a working project to download to STM32 Disocvery.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider [STemWin](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/PF259225?s_searchtype=partnumber), it is already supported on STM32F4.  In either case the biggest porting effort will probably be in supporting your specific display hardware.

Answer (score -1):

This link will help to implement STemWin on STM32F4.. [Link to blog](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=https%3A%2F%2Fmy%2Est%2Ecom%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2Fcortex%5Fmx%5Fstm32%2FSTemWin%20on%20stm32f4%20discovery%20problem&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=3303)..
It can be easily ported if the drivers for LCD and Touch are properly configured.